# Aggregate total by user in a list from Many to Many

Tags: django

I wish you a good year :)

I got a question. How I can get the total amount (prix + prix + ...) for each user who belongs to `friends` (Reservation's model).

I'm able to do it with request user:

```
context['user_total'] = RerservationOrder.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).filter(resa_order_reservation=self.object).aggregate(total=models.Sum('prix'))['total']
```

But assume I got three friends = X Y and Z. How I can list the total of X / Y an Z

I'm stuck with this issue. Thanks in advance

```
class Reservation(models.Model):
    friends = models.ManyToManyField(User,blank=True,related_name='friends_reservation')
    resa_order = models.ManyToManyField('RerservationOrder',blank=True, related_name='resa_order_reservation')
    ...

class RerservationOrder(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    prix = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6,decimal_places=2)
    ...
```

Comment: But will that not give the same sum for all friends? I'm ot entirely following how you filter on `friends=self.request.user`, since that is in `Reservation`, not `RerservationOrder`.

Comment: yes it's user=self.request.user :) you're right @WillemVanOnsem

The issue is only the user which is connected can see the amount he has to pay. Assume X is connected, he can not see what Y has to pay and Z has to pay. I don't really how I can build a list of all the user with the total :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first filter the on the fact that the `ReservationOrder`s of the users should belong to given reservation, and then sum up the price per user:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db.models import Sum

User = get_user_model()

User.objects.filter(
    rerservationorder__resa_order_reservation=self.object
).annotate(
    total=Sum('rerservationorder__prix')
)
```

The `User` objects from this queryset will have an extra attribute `.total` that is the sum of the `prix` of the related `ReservationOrder`s. If a user has no such `ReservationOrder`s, the user will not be part of the `QuerySet`.

Note that you made a typo in the name of the model: it is `ReservationOrder`, not <s>`RerservationOrder`</s>.